# Toggle fn keys with Applescript in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, macos-catalina

I'm trying to create an Automation Shortcut that toggles the fn keys in the Touch Bar.

This is my approach so far:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
    //TO-DO: script that opens drop down menu in settings and changes it to display fn buttons

end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that i use for Catalina OS:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
activate
set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
reveal anchor "keyboardTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    delay 0.3
    set thePopUp to pop up button 2 of tab group 1 of window "Keyboard"
    set current to value of thePopUp
    click thePopUp
    if current is equal to "F1, F2, etc. Keys" then
        click menu item 1 of menu 1 of thePopUp
    else
        click menu item 3 of menu 1 of thePopUp
    end if
end tell

quit application "System Preferences"
```

Comment: In my opinion it’s good practice to not set delay values, unless it’s absolutely necessary to. Everyone’s systems are different and the delay values that you set in your code may throw an error on other people’s systems. I’ve also found that when dealing with AppleScript code and System Preferences, it’s best to make sure System Preferences isn’t already running and if so… quitting it first, because there are a few System Preferences sub menus, if visible will cause your script to fail. This code addresses some of the issues I mentioned https://pastebin.com/pd3Dp7aL

Comment: ...continued - Also, the beauty of the `reveal` command for System Preferences, is that the application will launch and not come to the foreground while performing other commands.  No need for the `activate` and ``set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard”`` commands.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else trying to make this work - I've finally gotten my solution to work. Tested with: MacOS Big Sur, 11.4, June 2021

The code is based here:
https://github.com/MrSimonC/Toggle-Mac-Function-Keys

but for brevity, here is the contents of the apple script file:

```
-- Apple Script (i.e. Use in Apple's Script Editor Application) to Toggle Function Keys / Media keys on/off
-- Tested on MacOS Big Sur (11.4) June 2021
-- Project Path: https://github.com/MrSimonC/Toggle-Mac-Function-Keys

tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    if UI elements enabled then
        tell application process "System Preferences"
            repeat until exists tab group 1 of window "Keyboard"
                delay 0.5
            end repeat
            click radio button "Keyboard" of tab group 1 of window "Keyboard"
            click checkbox "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" of tab group 1 of window "Keyboard"
        end tell
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    else
        -- GUI scripting not enabled.  Display an alert
        tell application "System Preferences"
            activate
            set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.security"
            display dialog "UI element scripting is not enabled. Please activate this app under Privacy -> Accessibility so it can access the settings it needs."
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

Hope someone finds it useful!
Simon.